# How to configure Apache to only allow access from local IP addresses?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server

I have an Apache server serving a few domains (virtual hosts). Inside one of them I want a virtual directory to be accessible only from the local network:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
  DocumentRoot "some_dir"  
  ServerName www.something.com  

  Alias /restricted "someotherdir_somewherelse"  
  <Location /restricted>  
    Order deny,allow  
    Deny from all  
    Allow from 192.168.1.*  
  </Location>  

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is no one can access the directory. It is always rejected.

If I remove the *Deny* directive then local computers can indeed access the *restricted* location, but outsiders too. I'm a little confused with the Apache documentation about the `Order` directive:

> Deny,Allow
>
> First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied **unless** it also matches an Allow directive. Any requests which do not match any Allow or Deny directives are permitted.

It seems that once the *Deny* directive is evaluated, *Allow* is not. I'm testing from 192.168.1.60 and 192.168.1.23.

Apache is 2.2 running on Windows 2008 foundation.

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming `allow from` allows an asterisk as some wildcard, but that is not how things are [documented](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html). Instead, use a partial address:

```
Allow from 192.168.1
```